# How to get record by ripple many association?

Tags: ruby, riak, ripple

I want to save data into riak by ripple https://github.com/basho/ripple , and I create one model:

```
class Person
  include Ripple::Document
  property :name, String
  many :friends, :class_name => "Person"
end
```

If there are two person model instances, how to know one person is other's friends or not ? like:

`person.friends.get(somekey)`

Answer (score 0):

As `person.friends` is an array you can call it like this:

```
person.friends.include? otherperson
```